# How to change resource qualifiers to show a button in different language?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app.it has a button in activity A called "Calculate".
I need to change the resource qualifier so the English speakers in the UK, that are using a "7" tablet (sw840sp) in "landscape" mode want to display their "Calculate" button as "Calculate sir". 
The background color in such a scenario should become "green".

How can i do that?

I tried to do that with creating a new emulator for tablet and it wont show anything.only error app stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout in the resource folder:

```
layout-large
```

or more specifically

```
layout-sw840sp
```

and in that layout's XML you should use a string resource with the ID you need for "Calculate Sir", in the standard folder, instead you create the layout for the other display sizes with a different string resource ID (....for "Calculate"). Hope it'll help you. Same for the color.